# Jasper Export XLS Multiline textfields

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a problem with export report in excel. I 'm using an Ireport.
I'm trying to print multiline text in textfield

(TextField parameters : Height=20, Font=Arial, Font Size=10).

I set the Positition Type = Float and  Stretch type= Relative to Band Height. Аnd I got this result: 
[image]

The last line is eating. Im 'trying to set the property Stretch With Overflow=true. I got the same result. What I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you getting same problem in pdf.

Comment: @user1791574 Not there are no problem in pdf, no problem when I print xls file. I have this problem only in xls file. And I don't understand how to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried `Stretch type= Relative to tallest object` for this.

Comment: @user1791574  Yes I tried. But it is not works

Answer (score 1):

Try adding bottom padding or spacing after on that cell.
You can also try disabling collapse row span property on the report, it solves some excel layout problems: